# SVG paths proximity detection

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a set of SVG paths and to send hit events when the mouse in in a certain proximity of the path. I don't want the proximity of the rectangular box around the path. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a hit area of a different (expanded) shape, or simply duplicate the path and add a large stroke. Assuming a markup such as...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="m169,83c75,-44 220,145 96,110c-124,-35 -171,-66 -96,-110z"  class="hitarea" />
    <path d="m169,83c75,-44 220,145 96,110c-124,-35 -171,-66 -96,-110z" />
</svg>
```

You could then do...

```
path {
   fill: black;
   stroke: green;
   stroke-width: 5;
   pointer-events: none;
}

path.hitarea {
   opacity: 0;
   stroke-width: 50;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

path.hitarea:hover + path {
    fill: red;
}
```

Or, if you don't need a stroke on the shapes then you can simply put a large transparent stroke and it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/MbsCh/

Comment: I'd recommend replacing `pointer-events: auto;` with `pointer-events: painted;`, since `auto` isn't in any spec yet.

Comment: A nice, clean example. However, I am dealing with a set of multiple SVG objects that are dynamically loaded, also they all use the stroke-width to draw the shape. Is there no poosibility to append this proximity hit on the object itself? It would be a bit of a challenge to maintain duplicates of the SVG objects in this setup.

Comment: you can create the duplicates when mouseover and remove them when mouseout.